# WiX Burn Bootstrapper and EV Code Signing Cert

Tags: wix, windows-installer, code-signing, burn

It's been reported to me by a customer that a WiX burn bootstrapper built using a standard authenticode signing cert (issued by Comodo)  works but when signed using an EV code signing cert fails with error 0x8007001 - Incorrect function.

Does anyone know if EV code signing certs are a supported scenario for Burn?

> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]i336: Acquiring container:
>   WixAttachedContainer, copy from:
>   C:\Users\redacted\redacted\scripts\windows\redacted.exe
>
> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value
>   'C:\Users\redacted\redacted\scripts\windows\'
>
> [0868:0D1C][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to
>   extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0
>
> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to wait
>   for operation complete.
>
> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open
>   container.
>
> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open
>   container: WixAttachedContainer.
>
> [0868:09D8][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e312: Failed to extract payloads from
>   container: WixAttachedContainer to working path:
>
> C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Temp{fa5cf27f-af6e-44af-9bc3-2fd0f59b5c5a}\047E315E60BD621D6C1149E476C124F5065E6D26,
>   error: 0x80070001.
>
> [0868:03BC][2015-03-26T21:10:04]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed while
>   caching, aborting execution.

Comment: I believe this was user error by my customer.  If anyone can confirm they use an EV cert to sign a WiX burn bootstrapper, I would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was user error by the customer.  They changed their signing commands when they switched certificates.   EV signing Burn does in fact work.